# Error: $update is not a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean.io

I have nested tree pages in the mean.io angular controller from mongo db:

```
{"_id":"54a67318250272254669fa93","name":"test page 1","parent":null,"active":true,"children":[{"_id":"54a67326250272254669fa94","name":"test page 1.1","parent":"54a67318250272254669fa93","active":false,"children":[{"_id":"54a67330250272254669fa95","site":"54a6730a250272254669fa92","name":"test page 1.1.1","parent":"54a67326250272254669fa94","active":false,"children":[]}]}]}
```

Then I show it like this:

```
<ol>
    <li data-ng-repeat="page in pages" data-ng-include="'renderer.html'">
    </li>
</ol>
```

and it is a renderer.html:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="page.active" data-ng-change="pageActive(page)" />

<ol data-ng-model="page.children">
    <li data-ng-repeat="page in page.children" data-ng-include="'renderer.html'">
    </li>
</ol>
```

this is code in the controller

```
$scope.pageActive = function (page) {
    if (!page.updated) {
        page.updated = [];
    }
    page.updated.push(new Date().getTime());

    page.$update();
};
```

ok, my proplem:
then I click to checkbox and call pageActive function - I have error in the firebug (because nestet object has no update function):

```
Error: page.$update is not a function
```

but then i click to checkbox not in the nestet pages - it works

because my nested page model is overwriting parent model

Comment: You're calling a function $update() on an object that we know nothing about. The only thing we know about is what the browser tells you: $update is not a function. Post the relevant code. Tell us why you think page.$update() should work.

Comment: I added a description that still need?

Comment: You're still not explaining us why you think $update() is a valid function to call? Where is it defined?

Comment: i add my mean.io service

Comment: You're not calling $update() on a service. You're calling it on `page`, which is the current element of the JSON array that your view is showing in the ng-repeat loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<li data-ng-repeat="page in page.children" data-ng-include="'renderer.html'"></li>
```

To

```
<li data-ng-repeat="childPage in page.children" data-ng-include="'renderer.html'"></li>
```

I don't know what you are referring to with page, but by using data-ng-repeat="page in page.children" you are overwriting whatever it is with the ng-repeat child, which does not have the function $update (hence it's undefined).

Comment: yes, you are right, child not have the function $update, but renderer.html include itself and will overwrite childPage